# MySQL CReate Function Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create function using phpmyadmin/mysql console. Without any luck. I'm getting info of syntax error.

Can anybody take a look on this function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCategoryList
(
    @NewsID INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CategoryList VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @CategoryList = ''

    SELECT @CategoryList = COALESCE(@CategoryList + ',','') + C.[Name]
        FROM news_categories AS NC
            INNER JOIN categories AS C
                ON NC.CategoryID = C.ID
        WHERE NC.NewsID = @NewsID

    RETURN @CategoryList
END
```

Comment: That's TSQL/SQL Server syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct syntax for a MySQL function. That's why you get a syntax error.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Did you try to copy this from a different RDBMS?

Comment: To be honest, I was adviced in another question to use it.